# Comfortable watching on logs of MySQL

Tags: mysql, logging

My problem is that: I have the app, which intensively discuss with MySQL-server and I need to check some issues in the incoming queries.

Is there any good tool to see what queries have been executed by the server ? Good, if it would be some GUI in MySQl workbench. And of course, I know about `mysqld --log=log_file_name`, but really the direct viewing of file doesn't look like suite tool to see logs.

Thanks for hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [JetProfiler](http://www.jetprofiler.com/) - I know it will let you do this.

Comment: Very good program, they have a free version and easy to install

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find a tool that meets your needs, you can always log queries and query errors within your app and review those logs.